# SQL slow when having subquery in in statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following statement:

```
 WITH foos AS (
    select regexp_substr('H50','[^,]+', 1, level) x from dual
    connect by regexp_substr('H50', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
), baars AS (
    select regexp_substr('G30','[^,]+', 1, level) x from dual
    connect by regexp_substr('G30', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
) 
  select 
  count(*) 
  from VIEW
  where foo in (
    'H50'
    -- select x from foos
  )
  and bar in (
   'G30'
   -- select x from bars
  );
```

When using the constants `G30` and `H50` it is really fast. However when I use the subquerys, it is realy slow (~5 seconds).
I have no idea why this can be the case. any ideas?

Comment: what you mean `use constants` and `use subquery`?

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Why do you use `where foo in ('H50')` and not `where foo ='H50'`? Not sure this has something to do with the performance issue you are facing, but still... (the same for the second condition of course).

Comment: Because I want to have multiple foos. I want to pass it as  string parameter like 'H50,H51,H52,H53'

Comment: So you want to know why `where foo in ('H50')` is faster than `where foo in (select x from foos)`? Check the [**EXPLAIN PLAN**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231)

Comment: explain tells me that the `select x from...` is cheaper

Answer (score 1):

For start, the inline views are not being used in the first use-case, as in not being executed at all.

```
with    t1 (n) as (select 1 from dual union all select n+1 from t where n <= 10)
       ,t2 (n) as (select 1 from dual union all select n+1 from t where n <= 1000000000000)

select  *
from    t1
;
```